# Android Studio not installing latest apk

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm generating my apk filename with some data from the last commit (commit id and timestamp). The apk renaming is working as expected. As an example here is the filename that is
 created: `MyApp_debug_de2de27_240317_1554.apk`

I then, for example, at 16:12 make another commit. The filename created is `MyApp_debug_0370898_240317_1612.apk`. Now, if I build the apk, my output directory has two apk:
`MyApp_debug_0370898_240317_1612.apk` and the previous one `MyApp_debug_de2de27_240317_1554.apk`, but the apk that is uploaded to the device is the older one. I know this because if, before building the new apk after the commit, I delete the old apk. I get this message:

```
 03/24 16:13:36: Launching app
 The APK file Z:\Builds\app-android\app\outputs\apk\MyApp_debug_de2de27_240317_1554.apk does not exist on disk.
 Error while Installing APK
```

If I then sync the project, `MyApp_debug_0370898_240317_1612.apk` is installed.

Any idea why?

Here is how I'm generating the filename.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.package"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName gitVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def project = "MyApp"
            def SEP = "_"
            def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
            def version = variant.versionName
            def date = new Date();
            date.setTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(gitVersionCodeTime));
            def formattedDate = date.format('ddMMyy_HHmm')

            def newApkName = project + SEP + buildType + SEP + version + SEP + formattedDate + ".apk"

            println("Creating app with filename=" + newApkName);

            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newApkName)

            println("OutputFile=" + output.outputFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    03/24 16:13:36: Launching app
     The APK file Z:\Builds\app-android\app\outputs\apk\MyApp_debug_de2de27_240317_1554.apk does not exist on disk.
     Error while Installing APK
```

This error will resolve first you will  click on build > clean project

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild your project. Follow:

Build>Rebuild project

And then build apk